# How to create card layout in a trading card game Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d, card-game

I am trying to create a card layout for my trading card game. Right now I use this code:

```
public class ClientCard extends Table {

    ClientCard(int cost, int attack, int health, String title, String description) {
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/"+title+".jpg"));
        Image image = new Image(texture);
        this.add(image).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10).height(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 7).colspan(3);
        this.row();
        Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));
        Label cardName = new Label(title, skin);
        Label cardDescription = new Label(description, skin);
        Label cardCost = new Label(cost + "", skin);
        Label cardAttack = new Label("", skin);
        Label cardLife = new Label(health + "", skin);
        this.add(cardName).colspan(3).padBottom(5);
        this.row();
        this.add(cardDescription).colspan(3).padBottom(5);
        this.row();
        this.add(cardCost);
        this.add(cardLife);
        this.add(cardAttack);
    }
}
```

It works, it shows the card data, but it looks pretty bad and it's not very compact, also I can't set the outer border for the Table (`table.debug` is not good). What I want is something like this:

[image: Card]

I want to use scene2d so it's easier to fill the card with the data I want (life, attack etc). Any idea how I could realize this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an answer for generic layouts or for this (or another) specific layout? If you want one for this specific layout I can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: For this specific layout would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this look? *(Green and red lines are only there for debugging)*

[image: result]

What I did to achieve this was to first separate the card into **three columns and five rows**; then I had the *Cost*, *Life*, *Attack*, and *S* field occupy the small **1st and 3rd column** and the *Image*, *Title*, and *Description* occupy the large **2nd column**. I then used a `Stack` ([docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html)) to stack the table of contents on top of the colorful background image.

The general structure looks something like this in code;

```
table.add(cost); //col1
table.add(); //Blank! Used only to create col2.
table.add(s); //col3
table.row(); //New row

table.add(); //col1
table.add(image); //Image only occupies col2!
table.add(); //col3
table.row(); // New row

table.add();
table.add(title);
table.add();
table.row();

table.add();
table.add(description);
table.add();
table.row();

table.add(life);
table.add(class);
table.add(attack);

stage.addActor(new Stack(background, table));
```

But this of course won't size the cells to the correct size. The exact size of the cells will depend on what your layout looks like but for this layout I decided that all red fields will have a width and height of `75`. With that in mind the exact code used looked like this:

```
/* Adds the "Cost" label and centers its text. */
table.add("Cost").width(75).height(75).getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
/* Important! Adds a column between "Cost" and "S". Used to
 * align "Image", "Title", "Description", and "Class". */
table.add();
/* Same as "Cost". */
table.add("S").width(75).height(75).getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.row();

/* Add "Image" to middle column with a height of 50% of the
 * background's height minus 75 (the top columns height). */
table.add();
table.add("Image").growX().height(Value.percentHeight(.5f).get(background) - 75)
                  .getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.add();
table.row();

/* Add "Title".*/
table.add();
table.add("Title").grow().getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.add();
table.row();

/* Add "Description". */
table.add();
table.add("Description").grow().getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.add();
table.row();

/* Add "Life", "Class", and "Attack". Same deal as "Cost" and
 * "S" */
table.add("Life").width(75).height(75).getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.add("Class").growX().fillY().getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);
table.add("Attack").width(75).height(75).getActor().setAlignment(Align.center);

/* Used to show the table above the background image. You
 * should probably use Table#setBackground(drawable)
 * instead of using a stack! */
final Stack stack = new Stack(background, table);
stack.setSize(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
stage.addActor(stack);

/*Shows the green and red outlines. ONLY FOR DEBUGGING!*/
stage.setDebugAll(true);
```

Some of the `grow()`, `expand()` and `fill()` calls might be unnecessary - you'd have to experiment for yourself.
If you have any questions just leave a comment and I'll try to answer them :)

Comment: Thanks, the layout seems to be fine. Any idea how can i set the background and border of the table, and the background for specific cells?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need to have images for every single cell I would highly recommend having whole card templates and use this as your background. Look at these [hearthstone templates](http://img13.deviantart.net/eb4d/i/2015/018/5/c/hearthstone_empty_cards___warrior_by_demaretc-d8edqiz.png) to see what I mean. This template can also include the border. You can set the background of a table with `Table#setBackground(drawable)`.

Comment: So I should use a single image as the template for my card and set it as the table background and then write the text and display the card artwork on top of it?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I would suggest anyways as it's simple and it seems to work very well (once again; Hearthstone). Basically just replace the current colorful background with your finished background :)

Comment: That's something you'd have to decide for yourself but I'd say in that case you should only combine the card template and card artwork - not title and description since you might want to change those at a later date (e.g. you realize that "When attacked: deal 3 damage" is too strong and wish to change it to 1 damage instead. Now you'd have to edit the image instead of just changing the text).